# Images open perfectly fine while opening online but when they are opened with Adobe Acrobat reader the borders are missing or of different thicknesses

Tags: graphics, border, adobe, frame

I am in a strange situation, I have just completed the report and downloaded but when I open it with Adobe Acrobat reader some random image borders disappear. although everything seems good when I compiled it in Overleaf apart from some warnings which are not related to those specific images.

when I open the same file in Gmail it open perfectly as well and shows all images borders fine.

here is the image when i open it using Adobe reader

[image]

the same image in overleaf and in Gmail and in other online pdf viewers.
[image]

when I try to change the image here or change the size then this image would have a proper box in Adobe reader as well but some other random image in the report would have a border issue already spent hours on it and I am sure there is an easy fix of it.

i simply use this code for all of my images:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[height= 8cm, width=14.69785cm]{images/image.jpg}
 \caption{caption}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: Very difficult to help if we do not know exactly how you include the graphics and how do you add the border; you should add a minimal example. Anyway, it smells as an antialiasing problem - try to see if things change by changing the zoom.

Comment: @Rmano I have updated the question. I simply used the graphics package and the same code for all images. and yes i tried to change the zoom in the reader from "Fit" one full-page" which was about 54% to 100% and it seems like the issue is with Zoom.
for some images there is a border issue at like 50% zoom level which get's resolved when i increaase the zoom and then it appears on other images

Comment: so borders appear and disappears at different zoom level but they keep disappearing while printing :(

Comment: So the border is *in* the bitmap image? If it's too thin that can create that kind of behavior, which is basically unsolvable when scaling bitmap images. If you have control over the images, the better thing in my opinion is to remove the border, and if you really like it, adding it in LaTeX (you can enclose the image in an `\fbox{}`). The other option is to make the border thick enough so that at any scale it will be more than a pixel thick, which probably means that it will be ugly.

Comment: Unrelated: using `[h]` alone is asking for trouble, please read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: i was actually using `[h!]` for image positioning sorry for that and have updated it in main question.  i took pics from the word where all the images got the box using Ms Words's picture border option.  \fbox works :). have to go through all pics